# Active Record in Rails not saving update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a module that is being inherited inside an active record.

In that module
I'm calling a function which gets an id from an external source and then updates the record 
I get update result = true but the record will not save the update

```
# This is shared between multiple instances of classes 
module External
  def get_external_id 
     external_client_id =  ExternalClient::get_id(self)
     # it used to be 
     # self.update_attributes(external_client_id:external_client_id,  external_id_updated_date: Time.now)
     self.external_client_id = external_client_id
     self.external_id_updated_date = Time.now
     self.save
  end
end
```

```
class InfomrationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  include External

end
```

when I try to use 
  `self.external_client_id`
I get null 
when I should get a random UUID from external service.
I have inspected the whole function 
The service returns a proper id and I can log it
the save returns true and I can log that but when I try to use the

The problem was that one of my validation was failing silently without raising an issue.

I had to comment all validations and then return them one by one to figure out which one was failing.

Comment: If you add a bang(!) behind the self.save then it will give you a better error message so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Other than the above comment, you could use something like `self.valid?` or `self.persisted?` to check for the save and then print `self.errors` if it wasn't saved.

Comment: I have done that but save still returns true, which means the record was updated successfully but it was not.

Comment: This will probably require you to show more of your code to figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure that the table backing`InformationalForm` has a `external_client_id` method? Dumb question, but worth checking

Comment: It does have the column. I ran select statement on db :)

Comment: so I run save(validate: false), It updates fine but when I run save with validation. It does not mention there is any error but still no update

Comment: Have you made sure that `external_client_id =  ExternalClient::get_id(self)` is actually returning a `UUID` and not `null`?

Comment: Yes, I used debug and log and they both show that there is a UUID being returned and  when using validate: false it saves the UUID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation was failing silently, even though it should have been throwing an error.

Had to comment out all validations and return them one by one.

It was in a validation that had 
`if: Proc.new {}` block
I think the issue has to do with me calling a function in side the Proc.new 
and that function calls an inherited function that returns self.relation 
once that got fixed saving works fine